# If one series converges than the other does

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ be a series with positive terms that converges. Show that the following series also does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$.

Of course, if $a_n$ converges then by the Divergence test we get that $a_n\to0$. So $\exists N, \forall n>N$, $a_n<1$. From this should result that $\sqrt{a_n}<a_n$. But is that true if $a_n<1$? (I mean $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<\dfrac{1}{2}$ isn't true at all)

Comment: No, that's not true. You could use $ab\le{1\over2}(a^2+b^2)$ with $a=\sqrt{a_n}$ and $b=1/n$, and the Comparison Test.

Answer (score 1):

One may recall the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Special_cases)
$$
\left(\sum_{n=1}^N u_n v_n\right)^2\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^N u_n^2\right) \left(\sum_{n=1}^N v_n^2\right)
$$ giving here
$$
\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\dfrac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}\right)^2\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\right) \left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1{n^2}\right)
$$ then one may conclude easily.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Use Cauchy-Schwarz.

$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}\right)^2 \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Comment: @OlivierOloa yes you did, I was typing so I didn't see it.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Your answer is 1 minute older than this one, so it's probably fair to assume that OP started typing it before your answer was even posted...

Comment: @Anurag No problem ;)

Comment: @TheOscillator Your answer is fine, why deleting it?